# fabric -- can't run mv command

Tags: python, fabric

We need to transfer some files to remote machine using Fabric. But the requirement is while a file is being transferred, the first character of filename on the remote machine should be '.' (basically a hidden file). Once the transfer is done, we need to rename the file (I am using mv command for it). I am able to transfer the file but couldn't rename it on the remote machine.

for example, I need to transfer one file to remote machine as **.a.txt**. Once the transfer is done, I need to rename **.a.txt** to **a.txt**. I used below code but it is throwing error **'Could not contact remote machine : x.x.x.x error : Encountered a bad command exit code!'**

Below is the code I used.

```
for host, user_name in input.remote.remote_hosts.items():
      try:
         host_name = user_name + '@' + host
         fabric_connection = Connection(host = host_name, connect_kwargs = {'key_filename' : tmp_id_rsa, 'timeout' : 10})

         fabric_connection.put(exchange_file, remote_op, {'timeout' : 10})
         network_command = 'mv ' + remote_op + ' ' + remote_op[1:]
         fabric_connection.run(network_command)

      finally:
         fabric_connection.close()
```

Below is the error

```
ERROR    root:test.py:300 Could not contact remote machine : x.x.x.x error : Encountered a bad command exit code!

Exit code: 1
```

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Just a style note -- you want to have a space around the `=` in assignments, but not in parameters lists; so it should be `host=host_name, connect_kwargs=...`, etc; see https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: More importantly, as a _security_ note, you should use `shlex.quote()` to escape the filenames you substitute into shell commands. Something like `network_command = ' '.join(shlex.quote(word) for word in (['mv'] + remote_op))`, f/e.

Comment: That said, using `remote_op[1:]` is suspicious: How can you have more than one destination?

Comment: ...in general, if you want more granular error messages (that don't conflate connection failures with command invocation failures), I'd suggest switching from fabric to paramiko. And maybe, if your filenames have spaces, the above security note might be a correctness note too. (If you read any error messages written to stderr, that'll tell you a lot more than just the exit status alone does).

Comment: ...the other thing switching to paramiko will let you do is do the `mv` over sftp protocol instead of needing to run a shell command, so the `mv` shell command's syntax (and its exit status, and the need to quote/escape names when passing them on a shell command line) will become irrelevant.